# AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification issue in tvOS

Tags: swift2, avplayer, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am developing a app on tvOS platform. And facing a strange problem with `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification`. When i am playing the video and disconnect from the internet connection, the Notification called before the video end. i am not understand, how is it happen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.playVideo(videoUrl as String)
}

func playVideo(videoURL:String) {

    let asset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(string: videoURL)!) as AVAsset
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let playerObj = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    self.player = playerObj
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MyPlayerViewController.playerItemDidReachEnd(_:)), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: playerObj.currentItem)

    playerObj.play()
}

func playerItemDidReachEnd(infoNoti:NSNotificationCenter){
    print("==============Hi it is problem==============")
}
```

Comment: try `func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification){`

Comment: @Leo Dabus, I have used this function. But i want to use this function on the video end not the mid or any video duration.

Comment: You need to change the sender type from `NSNotificationCenter ` to `NSNotification`

Comment: AVAsset as AVAsset doesn't make any sense

Comment: videoUrl as String probably the same. What's videoURL type?

Comment: why not simply  `self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)`

Comment: But 'NSNotification' does to provide selector.

Comment: The object sent is a NSNotification, what do you mean ?

Comment: How will write the NSNotification.

Comment: `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver` is correct, you just need to change your method parameter type

Comment: `func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification){`

Comment: It is not working for me.